# Does Android's implementation of SELinux's M.A.C. inhibit root apps with root privileges from accessing app data?

Tags: security, android, selinux

**Starting with Android 4.4 SELinux's MAC is enforced. Does this mean that if an app somehow can get installed and exploit the kernel to get root privileges, that MAC will still prevent that app with root privileges from accessing private app data?**

Android Documentation says: SELinux can be used to label these devices so the process assigned the root privilege can write to only those specified in the associated policy. In this way, the process cannot overwrite data and system settings outside of the specific raw block device.
- http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/se-linux.html#use-cases

As a reference I am implementing a Mobile Device Management system and in the process I have to determine how secure Android OS is itself. That is why I need to know how secure corporate data stored on a device is to root-kits, spyware, and other malware.

Comment: Since this question is very specific to Android, I vote to migrate it to [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/). There might be more people there with knowledge about the specifics of the Android system.

Comment: Didn't really feel that it fit into there site.  You guys seemed more like the low level Linux experts. Buy if you feel it appropriate then thats cool. What topics can I ask about here?

Android Enthusiasts  is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Android operating system.

If your question generally covers...

Using your Android deviceUsing a particular app on your Android deviceTrying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device

then this is the right place to ask. Basically, what problem(with your Android device) are you trying to solve?

Comment: I didn't feel like it was offtopic (and I even had a look into the Help Center to confirm that), but I thought that you might find better help from Android experts at the other site. Looking at the number of upvotes for your question, it seems that at least some people find it interesting. Good luck.

Comment: Understood,  I'll post it over there too.  Thanks

Comment: Please remember that cross posting is generally frowned upon, so please add a remark on both sites and explain why you cross-posted.

Comment: I have posted the same question on their site,  explaining that it's been posted here too.  Hopefully we can get some answers.

Comment: Android is not Unix, this site is for “Un*x-like operating systems”. This mix-up comes from using Linux to mean Gnu+Linux.

Comment: It is possible for SeLinux to prevent root from doing stuff, though I know nothing about what android policies do.